# Problem in opening applications

Tags: applications

When i restart my mobile Samsung j5 2016  Or  shutdown so when i switch on my mobile. It start like from begning like when we by new phone . All that app doesnt work before restarting or before switching off i have. Please help me 
[image]

Comment: Install the Android SDK on your computer, connect your phone to the computer, enable ADB and execute `adb logcat` while opening the app that crashes. Usually you will see the internal error message on the logcat output. With that error message there is at least a chance to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Such an error can occur because of several different reasons and all these reasons come into existence due to one reason:

System or CPU failed to handle that app properly.

Messenger is a heavy application that will use a huge portion of your RAM and CPU while running and sometimes, to run system apps, the phone has to abandon these processes. That is why your apps keeps stopping (also, you are using a Samsung phone, so the UI uses more memory then the standard Android UI).

For a better experience, you have to keep your device clean by installing a cleaner app. You then have to remove cache and data of such apps regularly to have a smooth experience.